# WooCommerce Shipping zones based on state Ajax issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I have a problem with the shipping methods in WooCommerce checkout page, I have set the shipping depending on the state zone.

But when I test on checkout, and try to change the state, the shipping price doesn't change, as you can see in the screenshot below:

[image: screen]

On the other hand, when I refresh the page, the price change, so I think the problem comes from Ajax.

Can someone orient me to fixe the problem?

Comment: In WooCommerce, shipping zones doesn't take into account city, but only continents, countries (states) or postcodes… So maybe you are using a 3rd party plugin…

Comment: Hello @LoicTheAztec

Woocommerce, shipping zones takes into account city, because when i refresh the page, the shipping rate changes, but it doesn't change in real time...

Comment: I mean in WooCommerce shipping zones settings, you can only set continents, countries, states (regions) or postcodes, but not cities. **So The city has no effect on shipping rates** by default in WooCommerce without using anything custom like some additional code or plugins.

Comment: Okey, i get it. In my case its states (regions) not city, sorry...

Do you have an idea about my problem ?

Comment: On default WooCommerce using Storefront theme, I have checked for Algeria and when selecting any state, the shipping methods are refreshed and have the correct behavior. So, or you have wrong related settings, or something else is making trouble like your theme, a plugin or some customization(s) made by you. First, you should check for javascript errors that are making trouble using your browser inspector console.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec j'ai vu sur votre profil que vous parlez français, du coup je préfère.

Tout d'abord, merci pour votre réponse. En faite j'ai testé sur un tout nouveau site avec un thème de base, et j'avais le même problème. Ensuite j'ai pensé que cela provenait du serveur (j'utilise siteground), j'ai donc ensuite testé en localhost, et j'ai eu le même soucis. (toujours avec un thème de base), donc j'en déduit que cela provient du plugin woocommerce... 

Après inspection de la page de commande, voici ce que j'ai https://prnt.sc/11l9um0

Merci pour votre assistance !

Comment: In your question screenshot I can see some customizations on checkout fields, so it can be due to that checkout field customizations. Also as I have said before, this can be due to wrong related settings in WooCommerce.

Comment: Justement, j'ai déjà essayé sans plugin de personnalisation, et c'était la même chose, c'est ça que je ne comprend pas... même en localhost avec un thème de base et aucun plugin... Le soucis, c'est que quand j'actualise la page de commande le prix change, donc c'est dû à l'Ajax selon moi..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the `update_totals_on_change` class to the field that will have to activate the update of the cart total via Ajax.

In my example I added it to the `billing_state` field.

```
// adds the "update_totals_on_change" class to the "billing_state" field
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'bevingrosso_add_custom_address_field_woocommerce', 99 );
function bevingrosso_add_custom_address_field_woocommerce( $fields ) {
    $fields['billing']['billing_state']['class'] = array( 'update_totals_on_change' );
    return $fields;
}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

Comment: Thank you for your code, i'm gonna try it !